# Spring JPA @Query throws Optional parameter exception with Specification and Param

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm writing a larger query in JPA and need the pagination, specification and an additional parameter to work in it. I wanna function look like this.

```
 @Query(value = QRY_DATA, countQuery = QRY_DATA_COUNT)
     Page<NotificationUserSettingsPageResponse> findAllFrontend(@Nullable Specification<NotificationUserSettings>
 spec, Pageable pageable,  @Param("user_UUID") String userUUID);
```

when i try perform query like this i get error

> but parameter 'Optional[spec]' not found in annotated query

when i delete last param from query and function it work fine but when i add param JPA try to use Specification like param.
I mention that i need this param to use in join so i can't move it to specification. Query below.

```
    SELECT new pl.notification.dto.response.NotificationUserSettingsPageResponse(s.id,
s.userUUID, n.id,
n.system, n.name, n.category,
b.id, b.businessRule, 
CASE WHEN s.id > 0 
THEN s.isEmail ELSE 'T' END AS is_email,
CASE WHEN s.id > 0 
THEN s.isSMS ELSE 'T' END AS is_sms,
CASE WHEN s.id > 0 
THEN s.isPortal ELSE 'T' END AS is_portal)
FROM BusinessRuleConfig b
RIGHT JOIN NotificationConfig n on n.id = b.notificationConfig.id
LEFT JOIN NotificationUserSettings s on s.id = n.id AND s.id = b.id AND s.userUUID =:user_UUID
```

Comment: This is weird, you are using a specification and a parameter and specify a query? ! You are trying to mix 3 things together in 1 method. So which is it you want?

Answer (score 1):

Seems, you are extend just the `JpaRepository` for your repository.
You may extend your repo:

```
@Repository
public interface NotificationUserSettingsPageResponseRepository extends JpaRepository<NotificationUserSettingsPageResponse, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<NotificationUserSettingsPageResponse> {

    @Query(value = QRY_DATA, countQuery = QRY_DATA_COUNT)
    Page<NotificationUserSettingsPageResponse> findAllFrontend(@Param(value = "user_UUID") String userUUID, Pageable pageable);
}
```

P.S. And use Pageable argument the last.